# Wood burning stove pipe through the ceiling and roof

Tags: woodstove

I have a 16 x 22 cottage in Minnesota. Bought a small wood burner. Only one place inside to put the small wood burner. But, it is directly beneath a horizontal stud/joist of the truss. Would have to cut 14 inches of it out for square support box. Is there a way to block it in or not. Will I compromise the truss completely? Again, small cottage 16 ft wide and 2x4 run across the width. 24 in on centers in the ceiling. Bob

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will compromise the truss.

Each pipe supplier, if not, the stove supplier should have the allowable amount of elbows and the distance it can be offset with the elbows. Although I have only seen this with the insulated pipe behind walls and with additional supports. What you need may not look the best, but if it is allowed, it will keep your truss from failing should it be cut.